# How to fix a Python elif?

Tags: python

Okay I have the below code performing something I don't want it to do. If you run the program it will ask you "How are you?" (obviously), but when you give a answer to the question that applies to the elif statement, I still get a if statement response. Why is this?

```
talk = raw_input("How are you?")
if "good" or "fine" in talk:
     print "Glad to here it..."
elif "bad" or "sad" or "terrible" in talk:
     print "I'm sorry to hear that!"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that the `or` operator does not do what you want here. What you're really saying is `if the value of "good" is True or "fine" is in talk`. The value of "good" is always True, since it's a non-empty string, which is why that branch always gets executed.

Answer (score 4):

`if "good" in talk or "fine" in talk` is what you meant. What you wrote is equivalent to `if "good" or ("fine" in talk)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
talk = raw_input("How are you?")
if any(x in talk for x in ("good", "fine")):
     print "Glad to here it..."
elif any(x in talk for x in ("bad", "sad", "terrible")):
     print "I'm sorry to hear that!"
```

Note:

```
In [46]: "good" or "fine" in "I'm feeling blue"
Out[46]: 'good'
```

Python is grouping the condition like this:

```
("good") or ("fine" in "I'm feeling blue")
```

In terms of boolean values, that's equivalent to:

```
True or False
```

which is equal to

```
True
```

That's why the if-block is always getting executed.

Answer (score 2):

Use a regular expression. What if the input is "I'm good. Well, i'm more fine. Sorry, i feel terrible, my bad."
Then you'll have all conditions fulfilled and the output won't be what you expect.

Comment: if "good" in talk and "terrible" in talk: print "make up your mind"

Comment: If that's the input, what do you think should happen? Regular expressions are way overkill here.

Answer (score 0):

You have to test each string separately, or test for inclusion in a list or tuple.

In your code, Python will take the value of your strings and test them for truth (`"good"',`"bad"' and `"sad"' will return`True' as they're not empty), and then it will check if `"fine"' is in the characters of talk (because of the way the in operator works with strings).

You should do something like this:

```
talk = raw_input("How are you?")
if talk in ("good", "fine"):
     print "Glad to here it..."
elif talk in ("bad", "sad", "terrible"):
     print "I'm sorry to hear that!"
```

Comment: This will rule out all sorts of strings that OP's code would catch.

Comment: @aaronasterling, care to explain? It works in Ubuntu 10.10 Python 2.6.6. Of course, it only does strict matching.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
talk = raw_input("How are you? ")
words = re.split("\\s+", talk)
if 'fine' in words:
    print "Glad to hear it..."
elif 'terrible' in words:
    print "I'm sorry to hear that!"
else:
    print "Huh?"
```

From reading the other answers, we'd have to expand the predicates for other words.